# Values of all textboxes on a page - without knowing the ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a Chrome Extension that, when the user leaves the page, saves all the text from the textboxes on that page and outputs it to a file.

If I knew the IDs of the textboxes on the page, then it wouldn't be a problem, but the issue is that I need the extension to get the values of all of the textboxes on the page *without* knowing the IDs, as it will be a different website each time the extension is used.

Also, how would the information be collected? In a string? It would be nice to go down the page and add each textbox to a file, one by one, instead of one huge string.

I've never used jQuery or understood it, and there's probably a solution in it staring me in the face. If anyone suggests using it, please could you explain it a little bit?

Thanks in advance. I would post my code, but I don't know where to start - ergo I don't have any.

Comment: `$('input[type=text]')` should be a selector that returns the widgets you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function onClick(){
  var areas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
  for(var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++){
    alert(areas[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick="onClick()">Gather information</button>
```

Also see this regarding your "save to a file" question [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: This looks like it would work, but when I run the snippet I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined`....

Comment: @String I'm sorry, there was an formatting error :( I've edited my answer and it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

you could store it in array using [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), as :

```
var valsArr = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    valsArr.push( $(this).val() );
});
```

or create object with `name` as key and `value` as its value, like:

```
var valsObj = {};
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    valsObj[this.name] = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop

```
for(i=0; i < $("input[type='text']").length; i++){
   $("input[type='text']").index(i).value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector and apply it in an each cycle.

```
$(":text").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) : It returns an array.

```
var arr = $(":text").map(function() {
    return this.value
}).get();  //add join(',') after get() to get a simple comma separated list.
```

Instead of `input[type="text"]` you could also use `:text` pseudo selector.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x6k8ab2s/2/)**